# Need Json Payload for https://googleads.googleapis.com/v10/customers/948-412-1501:uploadClickConversions

Tags: rest, google-ads-api

I am trying to upload a conversion using REST API, as I  am writing code in rust hence no library is there for that, I am struggling to get the correct response, as, I am not aware of what should the proper request body, and there is no sample payload for a request given by google, the help available is not sufficient to make my request thru.

URL
https://googleads.googleapis.com/v10/customers/948-412-1501:uploadClickConversions

Header:
'developer-token': 'X8ec',
Authorization: 'Bearer ya29',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Post Body
{
"gclid": "0988098080",
"conversionAction": "Submit lead form",
"conversionDateTime": "2022-08-06 12:32:45-08:00",
"conversionValue": "10",
"currencyCode": "10",
"orderId": "11111"
}

Response

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "gclid": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "conversionAction": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "conversionDateTime": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "conversionValue": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "currencyCode": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "orderId": Cannot find field.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
"fieldViolations": [
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "gclid": Cannot find field."
},
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "conversionAction": Cannot find field."
},
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "conversionDateTime": Cannot find field."
},
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "conversionValue": Cannot find field."
},
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "currencyCode": Cannot find field."
},
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "orderId": Cannot find field."
}
]
}
]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I think u have invalid POST request
Look up [Google api documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v11/customers/uploadClickConversions#ClickConversion)

```
{
  "conversions": [
    {
      object (ClickConversion) <-- gclid must be here
    }
  ],
  "partialFailure": boolean,
  "validateOnly": boolean
}
```